Cycles of length-preserving OWF
I'm trying to solve the problem from this question.
I came up with the following inverting algorithm (supposing $$(\exists p(n))(\exists N)(\forall n \ge N)\mathbb{E}[cyc_f(U_n)] \le p(n)$$):
Input: y /* == f(x) for some x */

t_1 := nil
t_2 := y

for i = 1..p(n) * q(n):
  t_1 := t_2
  t_2 := f(t_1) /* == f^{i + 1}(x) */
  if t_2 == y: /* that is f(t_1) == t_2 == y */
    print(t_1)

I'm not sure about the correctness of this algorithm, but I wrote it intuitively.
I wanted to prove it could invert f as follows:
$$\mathbb{P}(f(A(y)) = y) = \mathbb{P}(cyc_f(x) \le p(n) \cdot q(n)) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(cyc_f(x) > p(n) \cdot q(n)) \ge 1 - \frac{\mathbb{E}[cyc_f(x)]}{p(n) \cdot q(n)} = 1 - \frac{1}{q(n)}$$
It actually doesn't seem correct.
My questions are:

How do I choose $q(n)$? Could it be any polynomial?
Why the length-preserving condition is necessary? Did I implicitly use it somewhere?

UPD 1: I figured out that actually if f is not length-preserving, then the for-loop is not deterministic (and hence f could reduce its input so that the loop would make less steps than $cyc_f(x)$). Are there any other ideas behind f being length-preserving?
UPD 2: Well, I think I could choose any $q(n)$,and just to achieve higher probability I could take higher degree polynomial.
P. S. Anyway, I'd be glad to read any criticism/advice towards my thoughts.
